# uninitialized constant Devise (NameError) with activeadmin

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, activeadmin

I got below error when I installed active_admin gem with rails4 version.

taken gem: `gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'`

```
/config/initializers/devise.rb:3:in `': uninitialized constant Devise (NameError)
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Do you included it in the `Gemfile`?If not include it and run `bundle install`.

Comment: If we include its work. but why so? as usually it should come along with active admin as dependency gem right?

Comment: I guess not.It should be added manually in the `Gemfile`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should include the **[devise gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)** in the `Gemfile`.Add this line to your `Gemfile`

```
gem 'devise'
```

Even though `Devise` comes as a dependency along with `ActiveAdmin`,you should manually include that in the `Gemfile` to load the `gem`.

For clarification,see this **[link](http://dan.doezema.com/2012/02/how-to-implement-a-single-user-model-with-rails-activeadmin-and-devise/)**.